# Is this summation notation correct? [SOLVED]

Tags: summation, notation, arithmetic

I have the following series involving n and k, where n is given and k is some chosen integer:

$$([n-k+1] + \cdots + [n-2] + [n-1] + n)$$
And I have the following notation:

$$\sum_{k-1}^{i=0} (n-i)$$

The series performs in an ascending order.

Am I correct?

Comment: Is it a coincidence that both your avatar and your sum are upside down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not very standard, you should write $i=0$ below, because the convention is that when the start is less than the end, the sum is empty (which means the sum equals 0). Note that the sum is the same if you begin from $n$ and end in $[n-k+1]$, so there's no problem in writing it as follows
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(n-i).$$
You can also write it like this if you want to keep the order:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} [n-(k+1-i)].$$

Comment: The  upper limit of the sum should be $k-1$ and the substitution $i\rightarrow (k\color{blue}{-1})-i$.

Answer (score 0):

The lower limit is by convention at the bottom, and its max limit is by convention at the top, other than that the formula looks good!

Answer (score 0):

For your question :$$([n-k+1]+\cdots+[n-2]+[n-1]+n)$$$$=[n-(k-1)]+\cdots+[n-2]+[n-1]+[n-0]$$

$$=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)$$